# How do I split a lubuntu root partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lubuntu

I've installed lubuntu on my old laptop and not knowing anything about linux partitioning I ended up with one full drive partition.

I have already some large files in that partition and I would like to split it so I can save my files in one place and install another distro.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to resize your current partition so that it is smaller. After you resize and made some free space, you can create additional partitions in the free space. Make sure you make a backup before you commit to any partition changes.

Note: some distro installers also come with tools to resize partitions, so you may be able to do it as you install another distro.

Comment: I tried this just now, but the resize option is greyed out.

Comment: @NunoCastro have you done it from a live cd, to make sure the partition is not mounted or in use?

Comment: Yeah, I booted from Live USB Linux Mint.

Comment: @NunoCastro there is a GParted [FAQ](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/faq.php#faq-9) entry on this that might help. If your filesystem is supported and you're sure it's not mounted, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I think gparted is outdated (0.12) in Mint. Only 0.14 supports LVM. Trying to update it now.

Comment: Of course resizing won't work if your disk is full.

Comment: @gronostaj the partition has plenty of space. Using the updated gparted did not work. :S

Comment: @NunoCastro you may also want to try the LVM tools directly. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume for example.